GCC Assembly Label Address Unexpectedly Truncated Without Warning In 16-bit Code
Problem Description
I encountered a bug related to label address truncation while using GCC to process assembly code.
This is the minimal example, where a label located at 0x8000 is loaded into a 16-bit register.
.text
.global _start
.code16

_start:
    movw    $label, %ax

.org 0x8000
label:

Here are the compilation parameters where I used -Ttext=0x8000 to set the default address offset.
gcc -Ttext=0x8000 -Werror -m16 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -no-pie -o test.out test.S

At this point, $label should be equal to 0x8000 + 0x8000 = 0x10000. This is a value that exceeds the 16-bit range, but GCC compiles it without error.
When I used objdump to view the disassembly, I found that 0x10000 was truncated to 0x0.
objdump -S test.out > test.asm 
test.out:     file format elf32-i386

Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    ...

Later, I will demonstrate the specific conditions under which this problem occurs.
To show this is not the normal behavior of GCC, I will provide a few examples.
1. -Ttext > 0xFFFF || .org > 0xFFFF
I set the -Ttext parameter to 0x10000 without using .org.
_start:
    movw    $label, %ax
label:

gcc -Ttext=0x10000 -Werror -m16 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -no-pie -o test.out test.S

GCC produced an error message (which is the normal behavior):
/tmp/ccFfC1x9.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Alternatively, using -Ttext=0x0 and .org 0x10000:
_start:
    movw    $label, %ax
.org 0x10000
label:

gcc -Ttext=0x0 -Werror -m16 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -no-pie -o test.out test.S

GCC produced an error message (this is also normal):
test.S: Assembler messages:
test.S:6: Error: value of 00010000 too large for field of 2 bytes at 00000001

2. .org < 0x8000 && -Ttext + .org > 0xFFFF
In this case, .org is less than 0x8000, and the sum of -Ttext and .org exceeds 0xFFFF.
_start:
    movw    $label, %ax
.org 0x1000
label:

gcc -Ttext=0xF000 -Werror -m16 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -no-pie -o test.out test.S

This is essentially the same as the first case, so GCC produced the correct error:
/tmp/cceqdykr.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

3. .org >= 0x8000 && -Ttext + .org > 0xFFFF
The above cases behave normally, but if .org is in the range [0x8000, 0xFFFF] and the sum of -Ttext and .org exceeds 0xFFFF, things become strange.
_start:
    movw    $label, %ax
.org 0x8001
label:

gcc -Ttext=0x8000 -Werror -m16 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -no-pie -o test.out test.S

It should have raised an error, as $label = 0x8000 + 0x8001 = 0x10001, which clearly exceeds the 16-bit range. But it compiled successfully:
test.out:     file format elf32-i386

Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
    ...

As you can see, 0x10001 was truncated to 0x1, which is very strange.
Conclusion
I have summarized the following behavior:
// Using start and offset to refer to -Ttext and .org values
// -Ttext = $start
// .org $offset
if start + offset > 0xFFFF
    if start > 0xFFFF
        // Error
    else if offset > 0xFFFF
        // Error
    else if offset >= 0x8000
        // Default truncation of start + offset (Why???)
    else
        // Error
else
    // Normal calculation of start + offset


Environment
GCC:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,d,fortran,go,lto,m2,objc,obj-c++,rust --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --lir
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 14.2.1 20240910 (GCC)

LD:
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.43.0

System:
OS: Arch Linux on Windows 10 x86_64
Kernel: 5.15.167.4-microsoft-standard-WSL2


Given your analysis, this seems like a clear-cut bug in GCC. Have you considered filing one?

@nneonneo Thanks for the suggestion. I also think it's a GCC bug and I'm in the process of applying for a Bugzilla account to report it.

A displacement of 0x8000 is negative in two's complement (it is in fact its own negative),  I wonder if the linker treats it as such and finds that 0x8000 - 0x8000 does not in fact overflow a 16 bit integer.

@fuz That's an interesting perspective. From my tests, -Ttext=0x8001, .org 0x7FFF produces an error, but -Ttext=0x7FFF, .org 0x8001 compiles successfully (with the address truncated). This indicates that the -Ttext parameter is not treated as a negative number, but the .org parameter (essentially $label) is treated as a signed 16-bit integer.

@fuz Another example, I can't use .org -1, but .org 0xFFFF works. This means the .org parameter is not treated as a signed 16-bit integer during assembly (which is expected).
However, at the movw $label, %ax step, when GCC performs relocation based on the -Ttext parameter, $label is interpreted as a signed 16-bit integer, causing it to become negative.

@ThousandPine Sounds correct.  People do stuff like movw $label-1, %ax all the time, so the displacement of the symbol has to be interpreted as a signed number.  The object file does not store if the number was negative or not, it just stores a 32 bit integer.  The linker can only guess what was intended and produce the overflow / truncation warning heuristically.
